# Mongoose aggregate: How do I get all document that does not have a column populated?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

**This is my mongoose schema:**

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userID: String,
  gender: String,
  dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})
```

**And this is my query**

```
userSchema.statics.getUser = function(callback){
  this.aggregate()
    .exec(function(err, result){
      callback(result);
    });
}
```

Some users might not have gender added when creating, how can I pull all document using aggregate that does not have the attribute gender populated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results are actually language agnostic so a simple mongo shell should suffice.
The results can simply be obtained in a find:

Consider:

```
> db.user.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ecf6b46a8b205baeb2cc58"),
    "user" : "neil",
    "gender" : "M"
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ecf6c66a8b205baeb2cc59"), "user" : "fabio" }
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ecf77c6a8b205baeb2cc5a"),
    "user" : "markus",
    "gender" : "M",
    "preference" : "any"
}
```

This works well for:

```
> db.user.find({ preference: null }).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ecf6b46a8b205baeb2cc58"),
    "user" : "neil",
    "gender" : "M"
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ecf6c66a8b205baeb2cc59"), "user" : "fabio" }
```

And also with **$match**  in aggregate:

```
> db.user.aggregate([{$match: { prefernce: null }}])
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("52ecf6b46a8b205baeb2cc58"),
                    "user" : "neil",
                    "gender" : "M"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("52ecf6c66a8b205baeb2cc59"),
                    "user" : "fabio"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("52ecf77c6a8b205baeb2cc5a"),
                    "user" : "markus",
                    "gender" : "M",
                    "preference" : "any"
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Look at [Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) in the MongoDB docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need aggregate for this. Just a regular old query will do.

```
User.find({gender: {$exists: false}}, function (error, users) {/*...*/}};
```

Comment: I needed aggregate as I am going to do project and group.